# How to simulate a Disk operation in a good way?

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request, project-euler

I want to simulate an operation on a disk, originally specified in [project-euler problem #566](https://projecteuler.net/problem=566). Here is a description of the problem.

I want to simulate a disk with arbitrary partitions, but only two coloring. For example, like this:

[image]

And I need only one operation: given a specific sector of the disk, e.g. from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, flip the sector and flip the coloring. Take the disk above as example, the sector would be:

[image]

Flip the sector upside down, and flip the coloring, we get:

[image]

Finally, inserting back:

[image]

However this took me hours to write and with a lot of condition checking and bugs. I started with a list with all angles that changed colorings, and the initial coloring, like `{"black", {0, 1/4 Pi, 3/2 Pi}}`,and the following functions suffered a lot from the cases which the sector crosses the starting point, although I used mod a lot. Is there any easy and elegant way to deal with such circular structure?

## Some of my current code

```
(*first 0: color counterclockwise on starting point; {0}: partition points; 360: total angle*)
diskStat = {0, {0}, 360};
getLastLEQPos[list_, elem_] := 
  Length[list] + 1 - FirstPosition[Reverse@list, _?(# <= elem &)][[1]];
(*get the color on angle pos*)
getStat[pos_, diskStat_] := 
  Mod[diskStat[[1]] + Mod[getLastLEQPos[diskStat[[2]], pos] + 1, 2], 
   2];
(*get selected interval*)
getInterval[diskStat_, currentPosition_, angle_] := 
  Module[{split, stat}, 
   split = Mod[
       RotateLeft[diskStat[[2]], 
        getLastLEQPos[diskStat[[2]], currentPosition]], 
       360] // (If[
         getStat[360, diskStat] == diskStat[[1]], # /. 
          0 -> Nothing, #]) & // Prepend[currentPosition]; 
   stat = getStat[currentPosition, diskStat]; {stat, 
    Mod[TakeWhile[Mod[split - currentPosition, 360], # <= angle &] + 
      currentPosition, 360], angle}];
(*flip the selected interval*)
reverseInterval[intv_] := 
  With[{end = Mod[intv[[2, 1]] + intv[[3]], 360]}, {If[
     end != intv[[2, -1]], getStat[end, intv], 
     Mod[getStat[end, intv] + 1, 2]], 
    With[{li = 
        If[end != intv[[2, -1]], Append[end][intv[[2]]], intv[[2]]]}, 
      Total@li[[{1, -1}]] - Reverse@li] // Drop[#, -1] &, intv[[3]]}];
```

Comment: Are you already using `PieChart` or `SectorChart`? Those might reduce the burden of creating the graphics. Also, I'm not sure I understand the conditions of the problem, I.e. when do you need a switch etc. Can you share your code attempts?

Comment: @MarcoB Actually the visualization part is not very important. The trouble happens when I try to process the list representing the disk. I will post some code later when I have access to computer.

Comment: @MarcoB You only need a switch when you specify a sector to switch, i.e. manually. But I need to preform lots of switches, that's why I am seeking a better approach.

Comment: Let's say you have borders on 0, Pi/2, Pi, 3Pi/2. Now, what happens when I take 0-Pi/4 for that operation? Should same color sectors merge on 0?

Comment: @Kuba Thanks a lot for looking at my problem! In that case, if the disk starts with white, then you will have 0-Pi/2 to be white. Now we perform "flip and invert", flip: nothing happens; invert: 0-Pi/4 becomes black.

Comment: @Kuba whenever there are two neighbor sectors with same color after the operation, they become one because you can't distinguish the difference. The "merging" happens only because of my way of representation.

Comment: @Kuba well in my representation, since I start from 0, it would be something like `{0(*starting color white*), {0, Pi/4, 3Pi/2}}`, they didn't merge because it crossed the boundary. but if this kind of thing happens not at 0, they would merge

Comment: @Kuba the "border" representation I demonstrated may not be a good representation of the problem. Because I actually finished the code myself but with tons of `If`s and bugs.So I think there could be some elegant solutions on this sort of "circular list" problem

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ideas that might lead to something.

1. Is the idea to solve the Project Euler problem easily/elegantly, or to manipulate graphics?  This is relevant, because the Euler-project problem asks for a number, not a series of pictures.
2. Instead of manipulating the graphics, just keep a list of the angles.  For example, {{0,45},{60,360}} is the whole disk, except the wedge from 45 degrees to 60 degrees is missing.
3. Keep just one list of wedges, the black ones, say.  Everything else must be white, which could be generated from knowing the black ones.
4. Suppose we want to take a slice from -45 deg to 45 deg, and flip it over.  Suppose the only wedge in our list is from 10 deg to 25 deg.  This wedge will get flipped to -25 deg to -10 deg.  That is a big clue to how to easily flip any wedge.
5. If our slice is from 100 deg to 150 deg, the we rotate our wedge(s) counterclockwise by 125 deg, do the flip around zero deg direction and rotate them clockwise by 125 deg.

We will want to define a few operation on the wedges.  Here are some ideas for functions that would be nice to have:

6. `slicer` is a function that makes a slice at a given angle.  For instance, if we want to make a slice at 130 deg, this function looks for any wedge (there should only be one) that spans 130 deg, and divides that wedge into two wedges.  We would apply it twice before we flip the wedges.
7. `chooser` is a function that takes our list of black wedges and selects the ones that are within two slices.  The selected wedges will be flipped over later.
8. `rotate` takes a list of wedges and rotates by a given angle
9. `flip` takes a list of wedges and flips the about the 0 deg direction.
10. `complement` is a function that takes a list of wedges within a slice throws them away, but keeps the blank space between them.  In effect, it takes a list black wedges and returns a list of the white wedges within a slice.  It should be easier to code this function than to maintain two lists of wedges -- one black and one white.
11. `merge` is a function that would merge adjacent wedges.  For instance, if we had the list of wedges {{30,60},{60,75}}, that is really just one wedge, {30,75}.  We can use MMA's `Interval` function here.
12. `step` is a (poorly named) function that determines the two angles of the next slice.  It then applies the `slice` function at each angle.  Next, it picks out the wedges within the slice angles.  Then it applies `rotate` to selected wedges, applies `flip` to the rotated wedges and applies `complement` to the flipped wedges.  Then it rotates the new wedges back and, finally, adds the new wedges to the list of black wedges and does a `merge` on the list.
13. `display` is a function that takes any list of wedges and displays them in the given color.
14. `solver` is a function that counts how many times `step` had been evaluated and watches for a solution.  If the list of black wedges has been returned to {{0,360}}, we're through.  The number of times `step` is evaluated is the function $F(a,b,c)$ referred to in the Project Euler problem.  `solver` can also apply `display` after each step.
15. `euler566` is a function that evaluates the `solver` for a series of integers $n$, adds up all the results and returns the sum.  This function is the $G(n)$ referred to the in the Project Euler problem.